# Access to other relations via Intermediate Table Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm working on a role based system in laravel.

Suppose we have three models:

**User** :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id')->using(UserRole::class);
    }

}
```

**Role** :

```
class Role extends EntrustRole
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\User::class, 'role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id')->using(UserRole::class);
    }
}
```

**Branch :**

```
class Branch extends Model
{
    public function user_roles()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(\App\UserRole::class, 'roleable');
    }
}
```

Each User can have some roles on different Branches(or do not working on any Branch). because of that I changed `role_user` table to a Model like this :

```
class UserRole extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'role_user';

    public function roleable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function role()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

That have this structure :

```
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------+
| user_id | role_id | roleable_id |         roleable_type          |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------+
|       1 |       2 | null        | null                           | 
|       1 |       3 | null        | null                           | 
|       8 |       3 | 1           | Modules\Branch\Entities\Branch |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

Now I want to get all Users that works on a specific branch via relations defined in those models. But I do not know.

I want to define a `users()` relation on Branch model that do what I want. But I do not know how?